# Suggestions for learning probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

**The Short question:** Where can I find a book for probability and statistics book that teaches them  from  scratch in a **rigorous** (very important condition)  way ? The book must not be elementary, but it has to start from scratch.( For example, I think Lang/Hungerford algebra begin by defining what a group is, in that sense they start from scratch.)

**The long question:** I only took an engineering course in probability and statistics. In my opinion, it is very louzy/non-rigorous. You may assume, I have no knowledge of probability and statistics. I have to take an independent study statistics course this year. I am allowed to choose a book for the course. It has to be a statistics course. My instructor assumes I know probability because I took the course mentioned above.( I admit I  have a poor understanding of probability and this irritates me a lot) . I'd like ato have a book that is:

1) Rigorous

2) It has a significant statistics part

3)It teaches the amount of probability needed to to do statistics

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Statistical Inference by George Casella and Roger L. Berger.
It's the book I used for my graduate inference class.